# Thread.Culture not being respected for model-binding in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, culture

To allow for culture-specific values to be bound correctly I have this ModelBinder:

```
public class CultureAwareModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

        BaseController controller = (BaseController)controllerContext.Controller;

        CultureInfo culture  = controller.Settings.Culture;
        CultureInfo language = controller.Settings.Language;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture   = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = language;

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

(`BaseController.Settings` is a property that exposes the correct `CultureInfo` for the current application's user).

I set it up like so

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CultureAwareModelBinder();
}
```

When I debug and step-through my code, the Thread.Culture is being set correctly, however my model keeps getting the wrong values.

This is my model:

```
public class EventModel {

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

When I specify "10/6/2013" for either field in my web-browser and hit submit, and when the culture is "en-GB" (and I checked the thread's DateTimeFormat is indeed set to `dd/MM/yyyy`), MVC receives it as the 6th October 2013, not the 10th June 2013.

I don't know why this is happening, and unfortunately I can't source-step into the actual model-binding. Why is it not respecting the thread culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **way too late** to set the current culture in the model binder. This should be done much earlier in the execution pipeline. For example in the `Application_BeginRequest` event in your `Global.asax`.

Comment: Culture is per-user, `Application_BeginRequest` is before ASP.NET has information about the current user, so I set the thread culture in `PostAcquireRequestState` instead and it seems to work. It's disappointing that `ActionFilter`s or binders can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. My solution was to use the `DefaultModelBinder` however instead of using an `ActionFilter` to set the desired culture I used a `IAuthorizationFilter` which has the same effect, however is executed before model binding unlike the 'ActionFilter' which is executed after model binding.

I appreciate that it is slightly inelegant/unorthodox use of the `IAuthorizationFilter` however it did the trick.